# How do I get the nested key element in a JSON object, using org.json?

Tags: java, json

I need the keys `direct` and `242`.
JSON structure:

```
   "advert": {
      "direct": {
         "url": "//direct.yandex.ru/",
         "params": {
            "add_type": "direct",
            "direct_page_id": 242
         }
      }
```

I use

```
jsonObj.getJSONObject("advert").getJSONObject("direct").getJSONObject("params").get("add_type")
```

but it doesn't seem optimal to me. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [JACKSON](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library to convert the above JSONString to POJO class and retrieve the data.
You can create a complex POJO class that will contain the above data.